# Issue to install EasyAdmin with composer in Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, composer-php, easyadmin

I started a new project in Symfony 5 and i tried to install EasyAdmin with `composer require easycorp/easyadmin-bundle` but I found an issue.

Composer log :

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.1.*"
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install easycorp/easyadmin-bundle v3.1.3
    - Conclusion: don't install easycorp/easyadmin-bundle v3.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install easycorp/easyadmin-bundle v3.1.1
    - Conclusion: don't install easycorp/easyadmin-bundle v3.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install easycorp/easyadmin-bundle v3.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install easycorp/easyadmin-bundle v3.0.1
    - Conclusion: remove doctrine/common 3.0.2
    - Installation request for easycorp/easyadmin-bundle ^3.0 -> satisfiable by easycorp/easyadmin-bundle[v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.2, v3.1.3].
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/common 3.0.2
    - easycorp/easyadmin-bundle v3.0.0 requires doctrine/common ^2.8 -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[2.12.0, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.13.2, 2.13.3, v2.10.0, v2.11.0, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.9.0].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[2.12.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[2.13.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[2.13.1, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[2.13.2, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[2.13.3, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.11.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.10.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.8.0, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.8.1, 3.0.2].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/common[v2.9.0, 3.0.2].
    - Installation request for doctrine/common (locked at 3.0.2) -> satisfiable by doctrine/common[3.0.2].
```

Do you have an idea to resolve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easyadmin has a dependency on doctrine/common v2 you need to remove your current doctrine version with `composer remove doctrine/common` then you can install easyadmin

Comment: Thank you for your help, I tried it too but there are issues with others dependencies ...

Comment: Just apply the same process with others dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Try change your composer.json file like this:

```
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.5",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "^1.11",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.10",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.0",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.6.3",
    "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "3.1",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.6",
        "symfony/asset": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/console": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.20",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/validator": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "5.1.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "5.1.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
```

and then type: `sudo composer update`. Works on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS :)

Comment: Please explain **what** you've changed and why. Also, you should not run composer using `sudo` unless you have a good reason to do so

Comment: I`ve changed version of doctrine: "doctrine/orm": "^2.6.3",
and added: "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "3.1",
Then necessarily do update of the composer.

Comment: Please add all such explanation to your answer by editing it

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in that list of error messages: `easycorp/easyadmin-bundle` requires `doctrine/common` in v2, while you have already installed v3.

You should downgrade that package such that the admin bundle can be installed. If you need help with that, please add the content of `composer.json` to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it was evident finally ! But when I try to upgrade, there are issues with other dependencies ...

Comment: If there are other problems on upgrading, please open a new question for this

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade doctrine/common and doctrine/persistence.

Try this:

`composer require doctrine/persistence:1.3.8 doctrine/common:2.13.3`

Then you should be able to call:

`symfony composer req "admin:^2.0"`